# python telebot У меня фотки отправляются сразу все, как сделать чтобы они отправлялись по одной и случайно

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня фотки отправляются сразу все, как сделать чтобы они отправлялись по одной и случайно

```
def func(message):
    if (message.text == "Прикольные картинки"):
     mem = [
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-62/s/v1/ig2/k1bsooyQQwiaG7IR3OIvR6g5MpiV8-rV7gYpZQkeuVEGcMYBrgDibpp6fbbbklKcbyE6o4zyT0Sw5iSoag_f2qv5.jpg?size=540x920&quality=95&type=album.jpg", caption="123"),
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://sun3.tele2-nn.userapi.com/s/v1/ig2/k_vMWJ9Pc9VvdahlAriXccnG_Xdv0Cp4N_S-Z5dD9mTHCaBwQ4EEMk0jAXA2c1-UkzT_tMy7xPsKAUFN5WfxQ_U6.jpg?size=1200x1600&quality=95&type=album.jpg", caption="123"),
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://sun9-north.userapi.com/sun9-84/s/v1/ig2/D9ds1eMljPLrAtye2Jj0x04nCdygkTMyoGOThYQnVHnurgsQjlnP1U07MCw0czhQ6WgFfqJi4uEUmoGuprukcBc9.jpg?size=606x326&quality=95&type=album.jpg",caption="123"),
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-56/s/v1/ig2/5s07VWsHS_t2NI_6N3JDmee1mfARYrjCpaq85Pp6cvrT81-F_AEXrCVCZ2-4tDB77ltqga3Opsg6FCLKJPeorL8B.jpg?size=450x600&quality=95&type=album.jpg",caption="123"),
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-8/s/v1/ig2/YLZzeuRyyV0TfpPPvYuIyJ8aLdsB8PS0MwfbBEKRtHMNeK4wL5jBS1JBQcTw-gxbBcCZ2qT3MfD6uUJHwVr1JEg_.jpg?size=300x573&quality=95&type=album.jpg",caption="123"),
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-5/s/v1/ig2/Uz8RjtL84Ps3q1QK1tjgGHKP8Bc4DxPmXWDlZ32izYp236o6raItYEXJnRDUSXDQvvrCaZD8qXBQTsiIv-EQu-m9.jpg?size=1200x1600&quality=95&type=album.jpg",caption="123")
           ]
     bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, random.choice(mem))
```

Answer (score 2):

А зачем вы делаете отправку в списке? Просто сделайте список ссылок.

```
def func(message):
    if (message.text == "Прикольные картинки"):
        mem = [
            "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-62/s/v1/ig2/k1bsooyQQwiaG7IR3OIvR6g5MpiV8-rV7gYpZQkeuVEGcMYBrgDibpp6fbbbklKcbyE6o4zyT0Sw5iSoag_f2qv5.jpg?size=540x920&quality=95&type=album.jpg",
            "https://sun3.tele2-nn.userapi.com/s/v1/ig2/k_vMWJ9Pc9VvdahlAriXccnG_Xdv0Cp4N_S-Z5dD9mTHCaBwQ4EEMk0jAXA2c1-UkzT_tMy7xPsKAUFN5WfxQ_U6.jpg?size=1200x1600&quality=95&type=album.jpg",
            "https://sun9-north.userapi.com/sun9-84/s/v1/ig2/D9ds1eMljPLrAtye2Jj0x04nCdygkTMyoGOThYQnVHnurgsQjlnP1U07MCw0czhQ6WgFfqJi4uEUmoGuprukcBc9.jpg?size=606x326&quality=95&type=album.jpg",
            "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-56/s/v1/ig2/5s07VWsHS_t2NI_6N3JDmee1mfARYrjCpaq85Pp6cvrT81-F_AEXrCVCZ2-4tDB77ltqga3Opsg6FCLKJPeorL8B.jpg?size=450x600&quality=95&type=album.jpg",
            "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-8/s/v1/ig2/YLZzeuRyyV0TfpPPvYuIyJ8aLdsB8PS0MwfbBEKRtHMNeK4wL5jBS1JBQcTw-gxbBcCZ2qT3MfD6uUJHwVr1JEg_.jpg?size=300x573&quality=95&type=album.jpg",
            "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-5/s/v1/ig2/Uz8RjtL84Ps3q1QK1tjgGHKP8Bc4DxPmXWDlZ32izYp236o6raItYEXJnRDUSXDQvvrCaZD8qXBQTsiIv-EQu-m9.jpg?size=1200x1600&quality=95&type=album.jpg"
        ]  
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, random.choice(mem))
```